# :has() jquery is not working correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to do something like below on my website:

```
$(".post-index:has(.wp-post-image)").css("background", "#000");
```

Js fiddle Example is working perfectly:
http://jsfiddle.net/rami2929/4x4t9/

But it'a not working on my demo website:

I would like to change box of background color that has image. How can I implement this on my demo site?

Any suggestions will be really appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Something to be mindful of: [jQuery Docs](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/#entry-longdesc). For performance purposes, it may be a better fit for you to use [`.has()`](http://api.jquery.com/has/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's outside the DOM ready function, change this :

```
$(function(){  
     $(".articleBox").click(function(){
         window.location=$(this).find("a").attr("href");  
         return false;  
    });

<!-- div mouseover change h2 color -->
    $('.articleBox').mouseover(function(){
        var color = $(this).find("a, .text-h2").css("color");
        $(this).find("a, .text-h2").css("color", "rgba(255, 156, 0, 0.8)");
        $(this).mouseout(function(){
            $(this).find("a, .text-h2").css("color", "rgb(51, 51, 51)");
        });
    });

});  

<!-- non image div change background color -->
$(".post-index:has(.wp-post-image)").css("background", "#000");
```

to

```
$(function(){  
     $(".articleBox").click(function(){
         window.location=$(this).find("a").attr("href");  
         return false;  
    });

    <!-- div mouseover change h2 color -->
    $('.articleBox').mouseover(function(){
        var color = $(this).find("a, .text-h2").css("color");
        $(this).find("a, .text-h2").css("color", "rgba(255, 156, 0, 0.8)");
        $(this).mouseout(function(){
            $(this).find("a, .text-h2").css("color", "rgb(51, 51, 51)");
        });
    });

    <!-- non image div change background color -->
    $(".post-index:has(.wp-post-image)").css("background", "#000");
});
```