# toggling with jquery, working on jsfiddle but not my site?

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle

why is my toggle function working on this jsfiddle but not my site?

Here is the JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/timur/bMfdD/4/
Here is the website: http://www.blindsdetroit.com/testing

```
<a id="clickMe" href="#">Type of Worker</a>

<div id="clickEvent" class="hide">
<ul>
<li>Rivermen</li>
<li>Boatmen</li>
<li>stuff</li>
</ul>    
</div>
```

Here is the jquery

```
$('#clickMe').click(function() {
$("#clickEvent").fadeToggle("slow");
});
```

here is the css

```
.hide  { display:none; }
```

Comment: jsfiddle wraps your JavaScript in a window-loaded handler.

Comment: possible duplicate of [:has() jquery is not working correctly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17073552/has-jquery-is-not-working-correctly)

Comment: There is a dropdown in jsfiddle that lets you decide "when" your code is run.  By default it is set to "onload".  You should change it to the option which best matches your real situation.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your code in `.ready()` so that it will run once the DOM is loaded

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#clickMe').click(function() {
     $("#clickEvent").fadeToggle("slow");
  });
});
```

or put your `JS` file before body `ends`

Answer (score 1):

Put your code inside document ready handler

```
$(function(){
  $('#clickMe').click(function() {
    $("#clickEvent").fadeToggle("slow");
  });
});
```

You don't have to write ready handler in your fiddle as your code is automatically wrapped with document.ready (*their is an option to choose from*)

[image] `<---` your code is executed when document is ready