# jquery: toggling the child of a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, parent

I want to toggle all the content in a `<div>`:

```
<div class="direccion">
    Dirección
    <div class="frm-section hide">            
        <label class="field prepend-icon">
            <input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="uit-input" placeholder="Dirección">
            <b class="uit-tooltip tip-left"><em>Dirección del paciente</em></b>
            <span class="field-icon"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></span>                      
        </label>
    </div><!-- end section -->

    <div class="frm-section hide">            
        <label class="field prepend-icon">
            <input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="uit-input" placeholder="No. Exterior">
            <b class="uit-tooltip tip-left"><em>Número exterior</em></b>
            <span class="field-icon"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></span>                      
        </label>
    </div><!-- end section -->
</div><!-- end direccion -->
```

I've tried multiple jQuery's on the forum, but none of the worked for me

Comment: Can you explain in more details what you are after?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean hide/show your `.direccion` content on a click of a button? If so you can do it by using **[jQuery Toggle](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)**

```
$( "#clickme" ).click(function() {
    $( ".direccion" ).toggle('fast');
});
```

**Online [example here](http://jsfiddle.net/3judbgzh/)**

Comment: ok this is weird, i was about to told you that i've already tried that and didn't work but when i paste my code on JSFiddle to show you, there it works don't know why is that D: here is the fiddle by the way 

https://jsfiddle.net/flick36/9tartra2/

Comment: maybe it's because you didn't implement the jquery library on the project you're working on, is it working now? Nice form design btw, clean and classic =)

Comment: i did implement it and, no its not working, the only thing that work is all the other stuffs except that
Thanks, that's how thing should be in my opinion

Comment: Ok i made it work like this :P
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17074201/toggling-with-jquery-working-on-jsfiddle-but-not-my-site
Thanks for the help!

Comment: Oh, ok. Check out my update anyways, the code before had some unnecessary parts